# How to disable Search button until user enters atleast 3 character in two textbox using Ext JS?

Tags: extjs

I have three four search fields. one of them is customer number and other are first name, last name and DOB. a user can search by 
1. using customer number
2. Or by entering two of the three other fields.

a search button needs to be disabled until at least 3 characters are entered in customer number

if they choose to use the search using fname, lname and dob, than search is not enabled until 3 character in first two field and DOB is not present.

How can i achieve this in Ext JS 6.0?

Comment: Listening to change events of the items and enable/disable the `button` component shouldn't be too hard. Show us what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

For enabling search button you can put one listeners and then write change function inside that. Inside change function get the search button first and enable/disable according to your condition.

I Placed the code for Customer Number according to your requirement. You can use same for firstname and last name.

```
 {    
    xtype : 'textfield',
    fieldLabel : 'Customer Number',
    id: 'CN',
    width: 125,
    name : 'customernumber',
    listeners: {
            'change': function(thisEl, newVal, oldVal) {
                var searchBtn = Ext.getCmp('srchBtn'); // srchBtn is id of your Search Button. 
                searchBtn.setDisabled(newVal.length < 3); // if length less than 3, then keep it disable
            }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved easily using form validation or by manually listening to change events of the controls. Kindly post your work so far so that we can help as requested by Alexander.